# Rails: Devise sign in error message behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Can anyone give any pointers to how we can customise Devise so that if an unauthenticated user visits the root_url, they are redirected to /users/sign_in but not shown the "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." error message?

To expand further: we want that message to be shown if the user tries to visit a 'deeper' URL (/controller/restricted_action) directly without first authenticating, but for someone with the app bookmarked as www.app.com we just want to redirect them straight to the login page without any error being shown.

Had a look around through the SessionsController (to ascertain whether a custom controller could work) and various other places, but can't see a place or how we can override the behaviour in this way.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should remove the flash alert message if redirected from "/" to "/users/sign_in".

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :keep_previous_url
  before_action :no_unauthenticated_alert_if_redirected_from_root

  def keep_previous_url
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
  end

  def no_unauthenticated_alert_if_redirected_from_root
    if request.fullpath == "/users/sign_in" && session[:previous_url] == "/"
      flash.now.alert = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony's suggestion above is good. Although I think we can improve on it slightly. With this below solution, there is only 1 `before_action` being called in the `ApplicationController` (the less the better since it's used by all), and then one in your root or home controller itself.
Also, it won't keep storing the `previous_url` unnecessarily in the user session, saving memory.

Add this to your `ApplicationController`:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :_no_unauthenticated_alert_if_redirected_from_root

  private

  def _no_unauthenticated_alert_if_redirected_from_root
    return if session[:requiring_sign_in_from_root] != true

    session[:requiring_sign_in_from_root] = nil
    flash.clear
  end
end
```

and add this to the controller that serves your root "/" url:

```rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :_check_if_requiring_sign_in_from_root

  private

  def _check_if_requiring_sign_in_from_root
    session[:requiring_sign_in_from_root] = true unless user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

The methods don't need to be private, but I think it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by doing the following:

```
authenticated :user do
  root to: 'home#index', as: :home
end
root to: redirect('/users/sign_in')
```

Now I don't the error message when going to the root route.

Source: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-authentication-for-all-pages